# Android EditText copy and paste from webpage, pastes formatted text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Please check the image below for reference. When I copy any text from webpage and paste it in Edittext in my app, Pasted text sometimes is already formatted and is different than default text. How can I keep pasted text to have default text style same as of Edittext.

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem? I don't see any.

Comment: Its font sizing issue. you cant not seen?

Comment: Kindly rephrase your question and tell more details, its unclear to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing spans in `afterTextChanged()`

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    CharacterStyle[] toBeRemovedSpans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(),
                                                MetricAffectingSpan.class);
    for (int index = 0; index < toBeRemovedSpans.length; index++)
        s.removeSpan(toBeRemovedSpans[index]);
    }
}
```